# How to post and parse data to node express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am trying to post this json to a node express end point

```
{
"data": [
    [
        "Audit Territory",
        "LA Antelope Valley",
        "LA Central",
        "LA East San Gabriel",
        "LA San Fernando Valley",
        "LA West",
        "LA West San Gabriel",
        "OR Inland, Coastal South",
        "OR West",
        "RV Central",
        "RV Coachella Valley",
        "RV South, Central",
        "SB High Desert",
        "Unassigned"
    ],
    [
        "Auditor Name",
        "Jeanna Bonds",
        "Dawn Wiley",
        "Janet Cortez",
        "Benjamin Sally",
        "Margie Watkins",
        "Jennifer Perich",
        "Tami Anderson",
        "Christy Brant",
        "Brian Lopiccolo",
        "Kristina Clark",
        "Tina Chester",
        "Ira Brown",
        " Unassigned"
    ],
    [
        "Not Started",
        20,
        13,
        24,
        25,
        24,
        52,
        117,
        33,
        48,
        54,
        44,
        69,
        2
    ],
    [
        "In Progress",
        1,
        2,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        18,
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        "Could Not Complete",
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        "Ready for Review",
        2,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        4,
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        "Needs More Research",
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    [
        "Approved",
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        2,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        3,
        3,
        0
    ]
],
"colWidths": [
    25,
    25,
    25,
    25,
    30,
    30,
    30,
    25
],
"colStyles": [
    {},
    {},
    {
        "horizontalAlignment": "center"
    },
    {
        "horizontalAlignment": "center"
    },
    {
        "horizontalAlignment": "center"
    },
    {
        "horizontalAlignment": "center"
    },
    {
        "horizontalAlignment": "center"
    },
    {
        "horizontalAlignment": "center"
    }
]
 }
```

It is not being parsed correctly in express and I am trying to figure out what is needed. I have tried a couple of different things.

I installed body-parser and applied it globally

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

that did not change anything.

*POST from the client

```
    const _fetch = model => {
  return fetch(`http://0.0.0.0:9000/create-excels`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(model)
  }).then(statusHelper).then(response => response.json())
}
```

I tried adjusting the model that was autogenerated for this api.

```
 const createExcelSchema = new Schema({
  data: {
    type: [[]] // Array
  },
  colWidths: {
    type: Array
  },
  colStyles: {
    type: [{}] // Array
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: (obj, ret) => { delete ret._id }
  }
})
```

This did affect the outcome but did not solve the issue. Here is the result that I am getting

```
 {
    "data": [
        [
            "Audit Territory",
            "LA Antelope Valley",
            "LA Central",
            "LA East San Gabriel",
            "LA San Fernando Valley",
            "LA West",
            "LA West San Gabriel",
            [
                "OR Inland",
                "Coastal South"
            ],
            "OR West",
            "RV Central",
            "RV Coachella Valley",
            [
                "RV South",
                "Central"
            ],
            "SB High Desert",
            "Unassigned"
        ],
        [
            "Auditor Name",
            "Jeanna Bonds",
            "Dawn Wiley",
            "Janet Cortez",
            "Benjamin Sally",
            "Margie Watkins",
            "Jennifer Perich",
            "Tami Anderson",
            "Christy Brant",
            "Brian Lopiccolo",
            "Kristina Clark",
            "Tina Chester",
            "Ira Brown",
            "Unassigned"
        ],
        [
            "Not Started",
            "20",
            "13",
            "24",
            "25",
            "24",
            "52",
            "117",
            "33",
            "48",
            "54",
            "44",
            "69",
            "2"
        ],
        [
            "In Progress",
            "1",
            "2",
            "0",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "18",
            "0",
            "0"
        ],
        [
            "Could Not Complete",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0"
        ],
        [
            "Ready for Review",
            "2",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "4",
            "0",
            "0"
        ],
        [
            "Needs More Research",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0"
        ],
        [
            "Approved",
            "1",
            "0",
            "0",
            "1",
            "1",
            "0",
            "2",
            "0",
            "1",
            "1",
            "3",
            "3",
            "0"
        ]
    ],
    "colWidths": "25,25,25,25,30,30,30,25",
    "colStyles": [
        "[object Object]",
        "[object Object]",
        "[object Object]",
        "[object Object]",
        "[object Object]",
        "[object Object]",
        "[object Object]",
        "[object Object]"
    ]
}
```

controller

```
    export const create = ({ bodymen: { body } }, res, next) => {
  _createExcel(body.data, body.colWidths, body.colStyles).then(result => success(res.status(201).json(result)))
    .catch(next)
}
```

route

```
      import { Router } from 'express'
import { middleware as body } from 'bodymen'
import { create } from './controller'
import { schema } from './model'
export CreateExcel, { schema } from './model'

const router = new Router()
const { data, colWidths, colStyles } = schema.tree

router.post('/',
  body({ data, colWidths, colStyles }),
  create)
```

model

```
    import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'

const createExcelSchema = new Schema({
  data: {
    type: [[]]
  },
  colWidths: {
    type: Array
  },
  colStyles: {
    type: [{}]
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: (obj, ret) => { delete ret._id }
  }
})

createExcelSchema.methods = {
  view (full) {
    const view = {
      // simple view
      id: this.id,
      data: this.data,
      colWidths: this.colWidths,
      colStyles: this.colStyles,
      createdAt: this.createdAt,
      updatedAt: this.updatedAt
    }

    return full ? {
      ...view
      // add properties for a full view
    } : view
  }
}

const model = mongoose.model('CreateExcel', createExcelSchema)

export const schema = model.schema
export default model
```

Comment: Show your route.  How are you accessing the variables on the `request` object?

Comment: I just added more info.

Comment: can you please show me how are you posting this data to express api?
are you setting the content-type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: just posted it. I did try to change this app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) (bodyParser.urlencoded) to (bodyParser.json)

Comment: I am just trying as many different things as possibel before seeking help

Comment: @texas697 Your original JSON is missing a closing curly bracket at the end of the data. Add that and see if your JSON is valid format.

Comment: its there. just needed to fix formatting on here

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm going to assume that you aren't posting JSON in the URL which means applying

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ ... }))
```

Won't really help you. What you most likely want is the [json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions) middleware that will parse a JSON formatted *body*

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: here is the result

Comment: [
    "OR Inland",
    "Coastal South"
   ]

Comment: the latter.. The actual value is "OR Inland, Costal South" it is considering it as a separate array

Comment: I can solve the issue by replacing the "," with something else before I post